# How many of each type should be produced in order to maximize profit?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The part that I don't understand how to get is the answers to a,b, and c.

[image: maximum profit]

Comment: Is there part of the problem missing?

Comment: Not really, unless you mean the equations for Revenue and Cost

Comment: $R(x)=2x+3y$,        $C(x)= x^2-2xy+2y^2+6x-9y+5$

Comment: Washington calculators produces two types of calculators, x thousands of type A and y thousands of type B per year. The revenue and cost equations for the year (in millions of dollars)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out after reading the question over. Thanks